# Making audio playlist with external audio files?

Tags: audio

In WordPress 3.9 there is a new feature that can make a playlist with uploaded audio files. I'd like to use external audio files. I use two web hosts. One for my website and one for my audio files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Playlist shortcode with external audio or video files

Here I explain how you can implement *idea 3* in my other answer, where we use the following shortcode structure:

```
[wpse_playlist type="" current="" style="" tracklist="" tracknumbers="" images="" artist=""]
    [wpse_trac src="" title="" type="" caption="" description="" image="" 
            meta_artist="" meta_album="" meta_genre="" meta_length_formatted=""
            image_src="" image_width="" image_height=""
            thumb_src="" thumb_width="" thumb_height=""]
    [wpse_trac src="" title="" type="" caption="" description="" image="" 
            meta_artist="" meta_album="" meta_genre="" meta_length_formatted=""
            image_src="" image_width="" image_height=""
            thumb_src="" thumb_width="" thumb_height=""]
[/wpse_playlist]
```

but this does not include the complete list of attributes, since the plugin is still in developement ;-)

### Example 1:

You can use for example:

```
[wpse_playlist]
   [wpse_trac title="Ain't Misbehavin'" src="//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/AintMisbehavin.mp3"]
   [wpse_trac title="Buddy Bolden's Blues" src="//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/JellyRollMorton-BuddyBoldensBlues.mp3"]
[/wpse_playlist]
```

in your post content and it will display like this:

[image: wpse playlist]

### Example 2:

Here's a more extensive example:

```
[wpse_playlist type="audio" tracklist="true" tracknumbers="true" images="true" artist="true"]
   [wpse_trac title="Ain't Misbehavin'" src="//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/AintMisbehavin.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" caption="" description="" image="" meta_artist="Louis Armstrong and His Orchestra" meta_album="78 RPMs and Cylinder Recordings" meta_genre="" meta_length_formatted="3:21" image_src="//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/louis.jpg" image_width="308" image_height="240" thumb_src="//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/louis.jpg" thumb_width="308" thumb_height="240"]
   [wpse_trac title="Buddy Bolden's Blues" src="//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/JellyRollMorton-BuddyBoldensBlues.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" caption="" description="" image="" meta_artist="Jelly Roll Morten" meta_album="78 RPMs and Cylinder Recordings" meta_genre="Jazz" meta_length_formatted="2:09"]
[/wpse_playlist]
```

with the following output:

[image: extensive - wpse playlist]

### Example 3:

Here's the vanilla version:

[image: Vanilla version]

generated from the shortcode:

```
[wpse_playlist type="audio" current="no" tracklist="yes" tracknumbers="no" images="no" artist="no"]
    [wpse_trac title="Davenport Blues" src="//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/DavenportBlues.mp3"]
    [wpse_trac title="Dixie Blues" src="//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/Louisiana_Five-Dixie_Blues-1919.mp3"]
[/wpse_playlist]
```

### Example 4:

Here's the video playlist:

[image: video playlist]

from this shortcode:

```
[wpse_playlist type="video"]
    [wpse_trac caption="Live widgets previews in WordPress 3.9" src="//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/widgets.mp4" image_src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/widgets_screen.png"]
    [wpse_trac caption="Another cool video showing how live widgets previews works in WordPress 3.9" src="//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/widgets.mp4" image_src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/widgets_screen2.png"]
[/wpse_playlist]
```

### Code:

Here's a first draft version of a single file plugin, but I will try to refine it further on github and post the link soon (**Update:** https://github.com/birgire/wpse-playlist ):

```
<?php 
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPSE Playlist shortcode for external files
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/141766/
 * Version: 0.0.1
 */

add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_playlist_init' );

function wpse_playlist_init()
{
    $playlist = new WPSE_Playlist;
    $playlist->init();
}


/**
 * Class WPSE_Playlist
 */

class WPSE_Playlist
{
    protected $type     = '';
    protected $types    = array( 'audio', 'video' );
    protected $instance = 0;

    public function init()
    {
        add_shortcode( 'wpse_playlist', array( $this, 'playlist_shortcode' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'wpse_trac',     array( $this, 'trac_shortcode'     ) );
    }

    public function playlist_shortcode( $atts = array(), $content = '' ) 
    {        
        $this->instance++;
        $atts = shortcode_atts( 
            array(
                'type'          => 'audio',
                'style'         => 'light',
                'tracklist'     => 'true',
                'tracknumbers'  => 'true',
                'images'        => 'true',
                'artists'       => 'true',
                'current'       => 'true',
                'loop'          => 'false',
                'autoplay'      => 'false',
                'id'            => '',
                'width'         => '',
                'height'        => '',
            ), $atts, 'wpse_playlist_shortcode' );

        //----------
        // Input
        //----------
        $atts['id']           = esc_attr( $atts['id'] );
        $atts['type']         = esc_attr( $atts['type'] );
        $atts['style']        = esc_attr( $atts['style'] );
        $atts['tracklist']    = filter_var( $atts['tracklist'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );
        $atts['tracknumbers'] = filter_var( $atts['tracknumbers'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );
        $atts['images']       = filter_var( $atts['images'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );
        $atts['autoplay']     = filter_var( $atts['current'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );

        // Audio specific:
        $atts['artists']      = filter_var( $atts['artists'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );
        $atts['current']      = filter_var( $atts['current'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );

        // Video specific:
        $atts['loop']         = filter_var( $atts['loop'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );

        // Nested shortcode support:
        $this->type           = ( in_array( $atts['type'], $this->types, TRUE ) ) ? $atts['type'] : 'audio';
        $content              = substr(  strip_tags( nl2br( do_shortcode( $content ) ) ), 0, -2 );

        // Enqueue default scripts and styles for the playlist.
        ( 1 === $this->instance ) && do_action( 'wp_playlist_scripts', $atts['type'], $atts['style'] );

        //----------
        // Output
        //----------
        $html = '';
        $html .= sprintf( '<div class="wp-playlist wp-%s-playlist wp-playlist-%s">', 
            $this->type, 
            $atts['style'] 
        );

        // Current audio item:
        if( $atts['current'] && 'audio' === $this->type )
            $html .= '<div class="wp-playlist-current-item"></div>';   

        // Video player:                      
        if( 'video' === $this->type ):
            $html .= sprintf( '<video controls="controls" preload="none" width="%s" height="%s"></video>',
                $atts['style'],
                $atts['width'],
                $atts['height']
            );
        // Audio player:                      
        else:
            $html .= sprintf( '<audio controls="controls" preload="metadata"></audio>', 
                $atts['style'] 
            );
        endif;

       // Next/Previous:
        $html .= '<div class="wp-playlist-next"></div><div class="wp-playlist-prev"></div>';

        // JSON 
        $html .= sprintf( '
            <script type="application/json">{
                "type":"%s",
                "tracklist":%b,
                "tracknumbers":%b,
                "images":%b,
                "artists":%b,
                "tracks":[%s]
            }</script></div>', 
            $atts['type'], 
            $atts['tracklist'], 
            $atts['tracknumbers'],  
            $atts['images'],
            $atts['artists'],
            $content
        );

        return $html;
    }

    public function trac_shortcode( $atts = array(), $content = '' ) 
    {        
        $atts = shortcode_atts( 
            array(
            'src'                   => '',
            'type'                  => ( 'video' === $this->type ) ? 'video/mp4' : 'audio/mpeg',
            'title'                 => '',
            'caption'               => '',
            'description'           => '',
            'image_src'             => sprintf( '%s/wp-includes/images/media/%s.png', get_site_url(), $this->type ),
            'image_width'           => '48',
            'image_height'          => '64',
            'thumb_src'             => sprintf( '%s/wp-includes/images/media/%s.png', get_site_url(), $this->type ),
            'thumb_width'           => '48',
            'thumb_height'          => '64',
            'meta_artist'           => '',
            'meta_album'            => '',
            'meta_genre'            => '',
            'meta_length_formatted' => '',
            'dimensions_original_width'  => '300',
            'dimensions_original_height' => '200',
            'dimensions_resized_width'   => '600',
            'dimensions_resized_height'  => '400',
        ), $atts, 'wpse_trac_shortcode' );

        //----------
        // Input
        //----------
        $data['src']                      = esc_url( $atts['src'] );
        $data['title']                    = sanitize_text_field( $atts['title'] );
        $data['type']                     = sanitize_text_field( $atts['type'] );
        $data['caption']                  = sanitize_text_field( $atts['caption'] );
        $data['description']              = sanitize_text_field( $atts['description'] );
        $data['image']['src']             = esc_url( $atts['image_src'] );
        $data['image']['width']           = intval( $atts['image_width'] );
        $data['image']['height']          = intval( $atts['image_height'] );
        $data['thumb']['src']             = esc_url( $atts['thumb_src'] );
        $data['thumb']['width']           = intval( $atts['thumb_width'] );
        $data['thumb']['height']          = intval( $atts['thumb_height'] );
        $data['meta']['length_formatted'] = sanitize_text_field( $atts['meta_length_formatted'] );

        // Video related:
        if( 'video' === $this->type ) 
        {
            $data['dimensions']['original']['width']  = sanitize_text_field( $atts['dimensions_original_width'] );
            $data['dimensions']['original']['height'] = sanitize_text_field( $atts['dimensions_original_height'] );
            $data['dimensions']['resized']['width']   = sanitize_text_field( $atts['dimensions_resized_width'] );
            $data['dimensions']['resized']['height']  = sanitize_text_field( $atts['dimensions_resized_height'] );

        // Audio related:
        } else {
            $data['meta']['artist']           = sanitize_text_field( $atts['meta_artist'] );
            $data['meta']['album']            = sanitize_text_field( $atts['meta_album'] );
            $data['meta']['genre']            = sanitize_text_field( $atts['meta_genre'] );
        }

        //----------
        // Output:           
        //----------
        return json_encode( $data ) . ',';      
    }

} // end class
```

Happy listening ;-)

Comment: I don't know how to thank you ! Amazing :)

Comment: Is there anyway to add download linkd beside every mp3 file name ?

Comment: @mahdiar Please check out my answer to your [question here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141767/download-button-for-wp-audio-player/142974), where I describe how you can modify the playlist template to your needs.

Comment: Here's the plugin on github: https://github.com/birgire/wpse-playlist

Comment: This answer is ... wow. +1

Comment: @kaiser thanks. I guess there are more refined ways to solve this. I'm glad if someone find this code snippet helpful  ... until there's a native way to handle external audio/video files in the playlist.

Comment: Hi I don't know why but I think the plugin doesn't work with wp 4.1.1 . Have try it ?

Comment: @mahdiar The plugin code here in this answer might not be working because of a tiny change in 4.0, but the updated [plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/birgire/wpse-playlist) works on my 4.1.1 install. Are you using the plugin on GitHub? Please use the issue tracker over there, thanks ;-)

Comment: Yes I'm using the github version . I use issue tracker there .

Answer (score 3):

When you construct a playlist and add it to your post content, you get a shortcode like this one:

```
[playlist ids="2855,1296"]
```

where the *ids* are referring to the audio attachments.

The playlists contains lots of audio meta data, so it's not possible to include external files this way.

Here are some untested ideas:

### Idea 1:

I wonder if it would work for you to upload the files to your main WordPress install at *example.com*, to collect the meta data and construct the playlists but then serve the audio files from your second host, *audio.example.com* ?

You can try to modify the audio files urls, in your playlist, with:

```
// Add filter for playlists
add_filter( 'post_playlist', function(){
    add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_url' ,'wpse_141766_wp_get_attachment_url' );
});

// Remove filter 
add_action( 'wp_playlist_scripts', function(){
    remove_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_url' ,'wpse_141766_wp_get_attachment_url' );
});
```

where

```
function wpse_141766_wp_get_attachment_url( $url )
{
    // Edit to your needs:    
    return str_ireplace( 'example.com', 'audio.example.com', $url );
}
```

### Idea 2:

You could create the playlist manually.

If you check out the `wp-admin/about.php?updated` page in your new `3.9` install, you will see that it contains a working playlist with external audio files. Here's the playlist with two tracks:

```
    <div class="wp-playlist wp-audio-playlist wp-playlist-light">
        <div class="wp-playlist-current-item"></div>
        <audio controls="controls" preload="metadata"></audio>
        <div class="wp-playlist-next"></div>
        <div class="wp-playlist-prev"></div>
        <?php
        $audio_icon_js = esc_js( includes_url( 'images/media/audio.png' ) );
        $wp_host = '//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/';
        ?>

        <script type="application/json">{
            "type":"audio",
            "tracklist":true,
            "tracknumbers":true,
            "images":true,
            "artists":true,
            "tracks":[{
                "src":"<?php echo $wp_host ?>AintMisbehavin.mp3",
                "type":"audio\/mpeg","title":"Ain't Misbehavin'","caption":"","description":"",
                "meta":{
                    "artist":"Louis Armstrong & His Orchestra",
                    "album":"78 RPMs & Cylinder Recordings",
                    "genre":"Jazz",
                    "length_formatted":"3:21"
                },
                "image":{"src":"//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/louis.jpg","width":308,"height":240},
                "thumb":{"src":"//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/louis.jpg","width":308,"height":240}
            },
            {
                "src":"<?php echo $wp_host ?>JellyRollMorton-BuddyBoldensBlues.mp3",
                "type":"audio\/mpeg","title":"Buddy Bolden's Blues","caption":"","description":"",
                "meta":{
                    "artist":"Jelly Roll Morten",
                    "album":"78 RPMs & Cylinder Recordings",
                    "genre":"Jazz",
                    "length_formatted":"2:09"
                },
                "image":{"src":"<?php echo $audio_icon_js ?>","width":48,"height":64},
                "thumb":{"src":"<?php echo $audio_icon_js ?>","width":48,"height":64}

            }]
        }</script>
    </div>
```

where the top of that page contains:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-playlist' );
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
```

But I think you can just use

```
do_action( 'wp_playlist_scripts', 'audio', 'light' );
```

or

```
do_action( 'wp_playlist_scripts', 'audio', 'dark' );
```

instead.

### Idea 3:

You could try to create your own playlist shortcode:

```
[myplaylist type="" tracklist="" tracknumbers="" images="" artist="" ]
    [mytrac src="" title="" type="" caption="" description="" image=""]
        [mymeta artist="" album="" genre="" length_formatted=""]
        [myimage src="" width="" height=""]
        [mythumb src="" width="" height=""]
    [/mytrac]
    [mytrac src="" title="" type="" caption="" description="" image=""]
        [mymeta artist="" album="" genre="" length_formatted=""]
        [myimage src="" width="" height=""]
        [mythumb src="" width="" height=""]
    [/mytrac]
[/myplaylist]
```

or

```
[myplaylist type="" tracklist="" tracknumbers="" images="" artist="" ]
    [mytrac src="" title="" type="" caption="" description="" image="" 
            meta_artist="" meta_album="" meta_genre="" meta_length_formatted=""
            image_src="" image_width="" image_height=""
            thumb_src="" thumb_width="" thumb_height=""]
    [mytrac src="" title="" type="" caption="" description="" image="" 
            meta_artist="" meta_album="" meta_genre="" meta_length_formatted=""
            image_src="" image_width="" image_height=""
            thumb_src="" thumb_width="" thumb_height=""]
[/myplaylist]
```

This looks quite clumsy, so you could try a simplifed version, with default values for the unused attributes:

```
[myplaylist]
    [mytrac src="" title=""]
    [mytrac src="" title=""]
[/myplaylist]
```

or some structure that suits you better.

Comment: Thanks . I think the third one is the best one . How can I do that ?

Comment: @mahdiar, I added a new answer based on the 3rd option where I included a first draft version of a plugin.