# Download button for wp audio player

Tags: audio

I'd like to add a download button to the core wp audio player (mediaelement.js).

How can I do that simply? Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm waiting for the solution .

Comment: I assume you mean the audio playlist, because of your [other question on how to use a playlist with external audio files](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141766/making-audio-playlist-with-external-audio-files).

Comment: "I'm waiting for the solution" Don't be rude. Your question as it stands should get now response. This is not a do-my-work-for-me-website. You need to at least show effort from your site, some research, some code.

Comment: I don't like to be rude but I should recheck my answer . Really sorry .You are compeltely right.

Answer (score 9):

### How to use a custom playlist template:

You can overwrite the playlist template with your own template:

```
/**
 * Remove the native playlist template and load our custom template
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/141767/26350
 */

add_action( 'wp_playlist_scripts', 'wpse_141767_wp_playlist_scripts' );

function wpse_141767_wp_playlist_scripts()
{
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse_141767_wp_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
}
```

where our modified template is defined as:

```
/**
 * Our custom playlist template.
 */

function wpse_141767_wp_underscore_playlist_templates() {
?>
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-wp-playlist-current-item">
        <# if ( data.image ) { #>
        <img src="{{ data.thumb.src }}"/>
        <# } #>
        <div class="wp-playlist-caption">
                <span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-title">&#8220;{{ data.title }}&#8221;</span>
                <# if ( data.meta.album ) { #><span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-album">{{ data.meta.album }}</span><# } #>
                <# if ( data.meta.artist ) { #><span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-artist">{{ data.meta.artist }}</span><# } #>
        </div>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-wp-playlist-item">
        <div class="wp-playlist-item">
                <a class="wp-playlist-caption" href="{{ data.src }}">
                        {{ data.index ? ( data.index + '. ' ) : '' }}
                        <# if ( data.caption ) { #>
                                {{ data.caption }}
                        <# } else { #>
                                <span class="wp-playlist-item-title">&#8220;{{{ data.title }}}&#8221;</span>
                                <# if ( data.artists && data.meta.artist ) { #>
                                <span class="wp-playlist-item-artist"> &mdash; {{ data.meta.artist }}</span>
                                <# } #>
                        <# } #>
                </a>
                <# if ( data.meta.length_formatted ) { #>
                <div class="wp-playlist-item-length">{{ data.meta.length_formatted }}</div>
                <# } #>             
        </div>

        <!-- BEGIN CHANGES -->
           <a href="{{ data.src }}" class="wpse-download" download="">download</a>
        <!-- END CHANGES -->

</script>
<?php
}
```

where we added this part at the end:

```
<!-- BEGIN CHANGES -->
   (<a href="{{ data.src }}" class="wpse-download" download="">download</a>)
<!-- END CHANGES -->
```

You might also need to add a special url to download the files.

The reason why I didn't add it within the `div.wp-playlist-item` selector, is because everything that's clicked on inside it, will start the player. The reason is this part of the `/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-playlist.js` file:

```
events : {
    'click .wp-playlist-item' : 'clickTrack',
    'click .wp-playlist-next' : 'next',
    'click .wp-playlist-prev' : 'prev'
},

clickTrack : function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.index = this.$( '.wp-playlist-item' ).index( e.currentTarget );
    this.setCurrent();
},
```

Here's the screenshot of our modified playlist template in action:

[image: Modified playlist template]

You could try some custom CSS to modify this to your needs.

Here's one kind of hack, that might need adjustments depending on the current theme:

```
<style>
    .wpse-download {
        margin-top: -22px;
        margin-left: -16px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .wp-playlist {
        padding: 25px;
    }
</style>
```

with:

```
<!-- BEGIN CHANGES -->
    <a href="{{ data.src }}" class="wpse-download" download="">
        <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
<!-- END CHANGES -->
```

in the presence of *Font Awesome*.

[image: Custom CSS download button]

**Further customization:**

You might also consider enqueuing your own version of the `wp-playlist.js` file where you replace:

```
'click .wp-playlist-item' : 'clickTrack',
```

with for example:

```
'click a.wp-playlist-item-caption' : 'clickTrack',
```

to be able to have the download link in the same row as the song title.

**Update:**

Updated the screenshots and added another example.

To make sure the file is downloaded and not displayed in the browser, we can use the `download` link attribute. I've updated the above with:

```
(<a href="{{ data.src }}" download="">download</a>)
```

It seems that the empty value will download it as current file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
/**
 * Our custom playlist template for mp3 download`.
 */
function wpse_141767_wp_underscore_playlist_templates() {
?>
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-wp-playlist-current-item">
        <# if ( data.image ) { #>
        <img src="{{ data.thumb.src }}"/>
        <# } #>
        <div class="wp-playlist-caption">
                <span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-title">&#8220;{{ data.title }}&#8221;</span>
                <# if ( data.meta.album ) { #><span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-album">{{ data.meta.album }}</span><# } #>
                <# if ( data.meta.artist ) { #><span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-artist">{{ data.meta.artist }}</span><# } #>
        </div>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-wp-playlist-item">
        <div class="wp-playlist-item">
                <a class="wp-playlist-caption" href="{{ data.src }}">
                        {{ data.index ? ( data.index + '. ' ) : '' }}
                        <# if ( data.caption ) { #>
                                {{ data.caption }}
                        <# } else { #>
                                <span class="wp-playlist-item-title">&#8220;{{{ data.title }}}&#8221;</span>
                                <# if ( data.artists && data.meta.artist ) { #>
                                <span class="wp-playlist-item-artist"> &mdash; {{ data.meta.artist }}</span>
                                <# } #>
                        <# } #>
                </a>
                <# if ( data.meta.length_formatted ) { #>
<div class="wp-playlist-item-length">
<span>
            (<a href="{{ data.src }}"><i class="fa fa-download" title="Download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>)
        </span>{{ data.meta.length_formatted }}</div>
                <# } #>             
        </div>
</script>
<?php
}
</script>
```