# How to get the ID of an item in an audio playlist?

Tags: php, audio, playlist

I'm using `wp_playlist_shortcode()` to output an audio playlist. For example:

```
echo wp_playlist_shortcode( array(
    'ids' => $track_ids
) );
```

Thanks to the idea in answer [142974](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142974), I'm unhooking the `wp_underscore_playlist_templates()` function and using my own version `prefix_wp_underscore_playlist_templates()` so I can customise the output of playlist items. For example:

```
add_action( 'wp_playlist_scripts', function() {
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'prefix_wp_underscore_playlist_templates', 0 );
} );
```

For now I'm just copying the contents of `wp_underscore_playlist_templates()` to `prefix_wp_underscore_playlist_templates()`.

Inside my custom `prefix_wp_underscore_playlist_templates()` function, a `data` object is made available but I believe this just contains "data" related to the track such as `data.meta.artist` and `data.content`.

**My question**

How can I get the post ID of the track when inside `prefix_wp_underscore_playlist_templates()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have an explicit filter for the data array so here are two workarounds that you might give a try:

**Approach #1 - As meta data**

We can add *attachment_id* to the *meta data* for each playlist item, via the `wp_get_attachment_metadata` filter, but first we have to register it via the 
`wp_get_attachment_id3_keys` filter.

Here's an example:

```
// Add 'attachment_id' as an id3 meta key
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_id3_keys', $callback_id3 = function( $fields ) 
{
    $fields['attachment_id'] = 'attachment_id';
    return $fields;
} );

// Add ?attachment_id=123 to the url
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_metadata', $callback_metadata = function ( $data, $post_id )
{
    $data['attachment_id'] = (int) $post_id;
    return $data;
}, 10, 2 );

// Output from playlist shortcode
$output = wp_playlist_shortcode( $atts, $content );

// Remove our filter callback
remove_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_url', $callback_metadata );
remove_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_id3_keys', $callback_id3 );
```

**Approach #2 - As query string**

Alternatively we can add the `?attachment_id=123` query string to the attachments url, via the `wp_get_attachment_url` filter.

Here's an example:

```
// Add our filter callback to add ?attachment_id=123 to the url
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_url', $callback = function ( $url, $post_id )
{
    return add_query_arg( 'attachment_id', (int) $post_id, $url );
}, 10, 2 );

// Output from playlist shortcode
$output = wp_playlist_shortcode( $atts, $content );

// Remove our filter callback
remove_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_url', $callback );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for both of these approaches. For the first approach, if I do `<# console.log(data) #>` inside `prefix_wp_underscore_playlist_templates()` to examine the `data` object, I don't see `attachment_id`?

Comment: This is untested but this should be in the meta data part in #1. This is constructed by peeking at the core functions. I'm not able to test it yet, but will try it later today ;-)

Comment: I had a super dumb moment. I was still using the `wp_playlist_shortcode()` function to output my playlist. I forgot to use the actual `[playlist]` shortcode. Approach works great, thank you.

Comment: great, glad to hear it worked.