# Display audio file in audio.php

Tags: attachments, audio

This is gonna sound stupid, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere:
I need to have an attachment page for audio files `(audio.php)`, but I have no idea how to display the media player on this page. When I use `the_content()`, it doesn't display the file itself.

I think I have to use the audio shortcode, but I don't know how to retrieve the id for audio files.

Comment: Check this out as it might be a duplicate question -> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270862/how-to-get-the-id-of-an-item-in-an-audio-playlist

Comment: I read it, but I don't think it's what I need, it seems too complicated for something that should be pretty easy to do with "native" wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure this out...
In the end all it takes is:

```
<?php
echo wp_audio_shortcode(
    array( "src" => wp_get_attachment_url() )
);
?>
```