# How to use a custom playlist template:

Tags: customization, templates, playlist

Can you tell me which file I need to locate on the server and add the code to for the mp3 download button to appear on my playlists?

Comment: What are you using to add playlists to your website? It sounds like this may be a plugin-specific question.

Comment: I am trying to use this to add a download button under each of the mp3 files added in a playlist but have no idea where or how to use this code https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141767/download-button-for-wp-audio-player?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Those first two blocks of code could either go into a custom plugin, or inside a theme's `functions.php` file. You would want to work with a child theme so that you don't lose these changes when you update the parent theme.

Comment: If you're not sure what you're doing with the code you have already, then you should probably hire a developer. Your question is too specific to your own website/theme/plugin which is unknown to us.

Comment: Thank you WebElaine - your information was very kind, courteous and helpful, I got it to work with a little googling and your point in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Mat 57 - Unfortunately some like me just need a point in the right direction. I already mentioned I was new to Wordpress - I am sure you were there at one point in time. If you are not here to be helpful then why bother to even post. WebElaine uses approximately the same amount of words as you did and got things going for me, yours... meh not so much. It always amazes me how arrogant some people can be.