# Error when overriding only some audio shortcode HTML output

Tags: filters, shortcode, hooks, audio

### Context

I have a function that overrides audio shortcode HTML rendering, thanks to a WordPress hook:

```
wp_audio_shortcode_override
```

I used it this way in an OOP plugin:

```
add_filter( 'wp_audio_shortcode_override' , array( $this, 'wp_audio_shortcode_override' ), 10, 2 );
```

In order to prevent all the HTML shortcodes from being overridden, I want to create a custom shortcode attribute:

```
player="default"
```

As far I can read from the docs and the source code, if I return an empty string `''`, the override should be off.
So I wrote this at the beginning of my render function:

```
public function wp_audio_shortcode_override( $html, $attr ) {

    $html = ''; // This is the value to disable the shortcode override

    if ( isset( $attr['player'] ) ) {
        if( $attr['player'] === 'default' )
            var_dump( $html );
            return $html;
    } 
    // After that, some code to fill the $html with thing to render,
    //   according to the shortcode attributes values
```

The next part of the function is how the shortcode must be overridden.

### Results

- Shortcode override without conditions works
- Adding the condition in the function, and write the corresponding shortcode attribute `player="default"` in one audio shortcode, works.
- Adding the same shortcode attribute value to all audio shortcodes in a post works.
- Having audio shortcodes with the attribute and some without on the same post **doesn't work**.

### Reproduce

For this, I started from a plugin example posted here: [Is it possible to control the width of the Wordpress audio player?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143272/is-it-possible-to-control-the-width-of-the-wordpress-audio-player)

### Assistance

What did I miss?
Why can I disable the override on all shortcodes, but not selectively on the same post?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, regardless how many `[audio]` tags you have in the post, and regardless which have whatever attributes. My guesses are either the logic in your handler is slightly off, or a 3rd party (i.e. plugin) is hijacking the default shortcode handler behaviour.

To test, remove your code and try the following - it should clearly demonstrate if (or if not) the default shortcode & filter is working as expected:

```
function wpse_209708_debug_audio_shortcode( $html, $attr ) {
    if ( ! empty( $attr['player'] ) && $attr['player'] === 'default' )
        $html = '{audio player:default}';
    else
        $html = '{audio player:other}';

    return "<p>$html</p>";
}

add_filter( 'wp_audio_shortcode_override', 'wpse_209708_debug_audio_shortcode', 10, 2 );
```

Report back and I will update this with a "real" answer.

Comment: Thanks for your support !
- I deleted my filter,
- I placed yours
- On a post, three audio shortcode, onewith player="default"
It appears as expected (two "others" one "default"). More, if I set `$html =''`, it works as expected (it renders "other" for the other, and the actual default player for the "default". 
So there must be something wrong in my code but I can't find what.
I uploaded my plugin on [github](https://github.com/X-Raym/wavesurfer-wp) if you want to take a close look.
I'll credit your for the help :)

Comment: My plugin just get accepted on official WordPress Repo as [WaveSurfer-WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wavesurfer-wp/), it will be easier to install it and test it.
I look forward to hearing from you. Cheers, and good luck !