# How to change WordPress embedded player size or show just the play button

Tags: embed

Even though I tried to alter the width of the embedded player size `[embed]` which looks this 
 [image: player]
  using `[embed width="50"  height="50"]`, but no matter what value I use it will not change the size. WordPress says [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) that it should work.

What else can I do to change the size? I just want to show the play button, nothing else.

And I don't want to change the content width like it is suggested in other posts on this website. I want this change to only affect the embedded player.

Comment: You probably need to set `overflow:hidden` somewhere.

Comment: Was it tested with the default theme, plugins turned off and clean browser cache?

Comment: my theme has no style added for this player. it seems the player won't take the size setting. on source code of the page I see 'mejs-mediaelement' will always display `width: 100%; visibility: hidden;`

Comment: Maybe [this for the audio player](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/143281/26350) helps?

Comment: thanks, but I can't use the audio shortcode, I can only use the embed shortcode

Comment: But I guess you only want this for audio files? The [embed] shortcode can also embed videos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're talking about embedding **audio** files, like:

```
[embed]http://s.w.org/images/core/3.9/AintMisbehavin.mp3[/embed]
```

The *audio embed* handler is registered within `wp_maybe_load_embeds()` and filtered through the `wp_embed_handler_audio` filter.

So within `WP_Embed::shortcode()` this generates to:

```
[audio src="http://s.w.org/images/core/3.9/AintMisbehavin.mp3" /]
```

so some of the [methods mentioned here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143272/is-it-possible-to-control-the-width-of-the-wordpress-audio-player?lq=1) for the `[audio]` shortcode should work.

Since we are using the `[embed]` shortcode, we could additionally add our own wrapper to support the *width* parameter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_embed_handler_audio', function( $html, $attr, $url, $rawattr )
{
    if( isset( $rawattr['width'] ) )
    {
        $html = sprintf( 
            '<div class="wpse_audio_embed_wrapper%s" style="width:%dpx">%s</div>', 
            $class = 1 * $rawattr['width'] < 120 ? ' audio-button-only' : '',
            $rawattr['width'], 
            $html
        );
    }
    return $html;
}, 10, 4 );
```

Here we use the `$rawattr` since we only want to check for the user input.

We add the class *audio-button-only* to the wrapper if the width is less than 120.

We then inject the inline style after the *mediaelement* stylesheet to hide the relevant parts like *duration* and *volume*:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
    wp_add_inline_style( 
        'mediaelement', 
        ' .audio-button-only .mejs-volume-button, 
          .audio-button-only .mejs-duration, 
          .audio-button-only .mejs-currenttime, 
          .audio-button-only .mejs-horizontal-volume-slider 
          { display: none !important; };'
    );
} );
```

This could of course be added to the relevant stylesheet instead.

We could also extend this approach to support other mini sized versions with corresponding classes.

Now we can use the *width* parameter within `[embed]` for audio files:

```
[embed width="28"]http://s.w.org/images/core/3.9/AintMisbehavin.mp3[/embed]
```

**Output:**

Play button:

[image: play button]

Pause button:

[image: pause button]

*Tested on the Twenty Sixteen theme.*

Comment: thank you! that almost works perfectly. the problem is that "00:00 00:00" is still there and it goes below the play button..I guess you don't see it because of the white background. I also see this if I copy it "Use Up/Down Arrow keys to increase or decrease volume." . any way to remove the time (and the text)?

Comment: I updated the answer with the `audio-mini` class approach from my previous answer, hopefully you can adjust it accordingly.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: do you get the wrapper and the inline css style? @whitelord

Comment: in the source code I see this: `<style id='mediaelement-inline-css' type='text/css'>.audio-mini .mejs-volume-button, 
          .audio-mini .mejs-duration, 
          .audio-mini .mejs-currenttime, 
          .audio-mini .mejs-horizontal-volume-slider 
          { display: none !important; };</style>`

Comment: Note that I did update the answer with the .audio-button-only class. How does the wrapper code look like? This seems to work on my Twenty Sixteen default theme, even with a dark background ;-) @whitelord

Comment: yes, but it still doesn't work.. it won't remove the volume, duration etc. you can see it here http://goo.gl/SB3z35

Comment: I don't see the `div.wpse_audio_embed_wrapper` wrapper in your HTML source code, are you using [embed width="27"]...  in your shortcode? @whitelord

Comment: ah, sorry. it works! many thanks! with the risk of demanding too much, may I ask how to make the player stay next to the text (on the same line)? the embed code is placed next to the text, but it falls one line below it

Comment: Good to hear it worked for you. I guess you could add a list tags (li) or div around it and move the text beneath the player and use e.g. float? Maybe play with absolute/relative position there within. But I wonder why you don't use the native playlist? If you're using external audio files then you can check my [answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141766/making-audio-playlist-with-external-audio-files?lq=1) that later became available as a [plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/birgire/wpse-playlist). @whitelord

Comment: your plugin seems great, so I installed. But, beside the fact that it appears two times in admin area, one activate and one not activated, with same names, it doesn't seem to work. I used the codes from your demo, and it looks like this http://imgur.com/wG0wng8

Comment: Please use the issue tracker on GitHub. Note that you might be using extra lines in the shortcodes? It works as expected on my demo page [here](http://xlino.com/projects/wordpress-playlist-shortcode-with-external-audio-or-video-files/).  @whitelord