# Hide download button from audio player

Tags: media, embed, buttons, audio

```
 [embed width="28"]http://audio.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview91/v4/e7/e0/fb/e7e0fbfb-5582-ee65-6a81-823b5ecf9186/mzaf_5076836927047056840.plus.aac.p.m4a[/embed]
```

Since WordPress was updated to version 4.7, the audio player changed: after pressing the play icon, the play button now comes with other options, "download" and "mute".

I want to hide those, and turn back to the simple play - pause

Below is the image:

[image]

In the past, after playing 'play', only the 'pause' button appeared as seen in the image below:

[image]

I want it back. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Tested your code on WP 4.7.1 and not able to reproduce the issue. Checked in FF, Chrome and Safari. I am on Mac OSX. Can you please provide more information - http://prnt.sc/dy1uvg

Comment: I have a function to reduce the size of the player, but I didn't think that could be a cause for this. please take a look here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228106/how-to-change-wordpress-embedded-player-size-or-show-just-the-play-button

Answer (score 0):

Hi another simple way is to add the following code to hide the download button. Please adapt width and margin top elements.

```css
.wp-block-audio:after {
    width:35px;
    background-color:#F1F3F4;
    color:#F1F3F4;
    content:'.';
    float:right;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-top:-95px;
    z-index:999;
    position:relative;
}
```