# How to make WordPress audio playlist understand the direct links of audio files shared on google drive?

Tags: audio, google, playlist

this is my first post here and I excited! I used [this approach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141766/making-audio-playlist-with-external-audio-files/141857#141857) to  make a playlist with external links of audio files I have in my drive but unfortunately It couldn't recognize the google drive direct link as a audio type file. Would you please guide me how I can solve this issue!?
Thank you in advance and sorry if my English is not well enough!
@birgire

Comment: What exactly do you see? In particular does it look like something at WordPress's end is rejecting the files, or do you see the Google Drive links in your page's view source and so it's the browser that's rejecting the files? What content types does the Google drive links return? (Check the network tab in your browser, or e.g. `curl --head <the link>`. Is it the correct audio type, e.g. audio/mpeg? Or is it something that either WordPress or the browser might not recognise as audio?

Comment: The method you linked to assumes that the audio files are directly accessibly by a public URL. Google Drive is not a web host, and does not support this, so files hosted there can't be used in this way. It would also almost certainly be a violation of their user agreement. You will need to host the audio files on a web server, or on a service that supports public direct links to the files. This is not something you can address in WordPress, short of using the Google Drive API to import audio files, which is far too much work when there's simpler solutions.

Comment: Got these errors when click to play an item in playlist: mediaelement-and-player.min.js?ver=4.2.16:12 GET https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download& 400
T @ mediaelement-and-player.min.js?ver=4.2.16:12
C.f.mediaElement.<computed> @ mediaelement-and-player.min.js?ver=4.2.16:12
value @ mediaelement-and-player.min.js?ver=4.2.16:12
value @ mediaelement-and-player.min.js?ver=4.2.16:12
(anonymous) @ mediaelement-and-player.min.js?ver=4.2.16:12
mysite.com/:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Comment: Also my audio files are pubic on google drive and some other players plugins I tried can recognize and play them as well as chrome itself.

Comment: Hope this helps https://github.com/birgire/wpse-playlist/issues/20

Comment: Yes It worked! Thank you so much dear birgire.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked and welcome to WPSE. Feel free to answer your question to mark it solved

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in comments section of my question, «birgire» had suggested to a user of his [plugin](https://github.com/birgire/wpse-playlist/issues/20) to change the google drive direct link as follow so that It can be recognized an played in the WordPress playlist:
A normal google drive direct link is something like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bz4YdwRI3rnCMFRoTmtSS0M1VHM
```

If you make sure the first GET parameter is the id of your file, It will be playable in WordPress playlist. So you need to remove the "**export=download&**" part of the google direct link. Above example should be like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0Bz4YdwRI3rnCMFRoTmtSS0M1VHM
```

The discussion about how we can use external links in WordPress playlist is [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141766/making-audio-playlist-with-external-audio-files).